# fdisk command is not listing the required commands like 'a'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fdisk, pop-os

I am new to the Linux environment and using the Pop!_OS Distro.

I was using **fdisk** to create partitions on an SD card,

`sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

But when I pressed **'a'** to set the bootable flag on the 1st partition that I created, it says

**'a: unknown command'.**

Also when I tried to set the partition filesystem to **FAT32**, using the **'t'** command, it doesn't list the **'W95 FAT32 (LBA)'** option.

What do I do? I am learning embedded Linux and this just put a handbrake on my learning progress for the last 2 days.

Comment: You probably want to use `parted` instead of `fdisk`. `parted` is newer and has better support of GPT partition tables (I think `fdisk` doesn't even support them at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` command to set the bootable flag is valid only for the DOS/MBR partition table. Same applies to `W95 FAT32 (LBA)` which is also DOS specific [partition ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type) so your SD card probably has a different partition table.

I assume your SD card uses the [GPT partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (you can check with `p`, for GPT it will say `Disklabel type: gpt`) so you either need to switch to DOS partition table by using the `o` command (this will replace the existing partition table and remove all partitions!) or use GPT-specific flags and [partition type GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs). You can set the bootable flag on GPT by going to the advanced menu with `x` and using the `A` command to toggle the flag.

Comment: Can `fdisk` even handle GPT tables correctly? Wouldn't it be better to use `parted` instead?

Comment: `fdisk` handles GPT perfectly as it's been the case for many years already.

Comment: OK, thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov. I started used `parted` at about the same time I started seeing GPT more so I wasn't sure.

Comment: You are right. The SD card was using GPT. I changed it to DOS. Had to read up a bit on those. I am able to set the flags now. Thank you. I'll try and understand how different ```parted``` works too.